# How to combine setNeedsDisplay with a content scroll?

Tags: ios, uikit, core-graphics

I implemented a custom UIView which draws complex graphics (via drawRect) that cannot be drawn any other way. Since the drawn items are on an extremely large plane (think world map), I could not use UIScrollView due to memory constraints. I manage my own origin and zoom variables and draw the graphics based on those. I also implemented gesture recognizers for panning, zooming in and out, double- and single tap, etc. It all works brilliant.

But I need an optimization: when the user is panning with his/her finger, I change my internal origin variable accordingly and call setNeedsDisplay. This works well on simulator and iPhone 5, but on an iPad 3 it's a bit slow (not too bad, but still noticeable). What I want to achieve is to call setNeedsDisplay only for those areas that need to be displayed (i.e. the newly arrived items on the screen that show up due to panning), and scroll (shift) the area that was already on the screen. Displaying 1/10th of the screen will be much faster than displaying 1/1, as I've already done optimizations to quickly determine which items fall on the screen and show only those.

In other words, instead of calling

```
thisView.originPoint = thisView.originPoint - 10;
[thisView setNeedsDisplay];
```

I wish I could somehow call

```
thisView.originPoint = thisView.originPoint - 10;
[thisView setNeedsDisplayInRect: CGMakeRect(320-10,0,320,480)
    withScroll: CGMakerect(0,0,320-10,480) scrollBy: CGPointMake(-10,0);
```

this is obviously just stylized code. It doesn't help to just scroll the contents of the view (although I don't know how to do that at the moment), since drawRect might be called much later, and possibly combined with another call to setNeedsDisplay.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider caching an image of the screen with `[self.layer renderInContext:aContext]` and `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` once the view has been drawn fully. This image could be drawn at different places as the user pans, eg. translated to the left as the user drags. Meanwhile, the necessary data would also be loaded asynchronously. After the user finishes dragging or after the data has been loaded, you would set a flag to let setNeedsDisplay draw in the required section, then caching the new image.

Also, the [CATiledLayer](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATiledLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) class does something similar to what you're looking for, but it would require a little more modification to what you already have.

Hope this helps!

Comment: There's no need to asynchronously load anything as all data is already in memory. The idea I have now is to scroll previously drawn stuff within drawRect, as the program knows exactly what was drawn before. Thanks for pointing out CATiledLayer, that looks interesting too.

Comment: Unfortunately, caching previously drawn image and using it for the next `drawRect` is just as slow on iPad3 as drawing graphics from scratch. The `[layer renderInContext]` and `[cachedImage drawAtPoint]` are just too slow on iPad3 to allow for smooth panning.

Comment: Huh. I've always found drawing an image faster than drawing from scratch (which in my case was a PDF so yours may be otherwise). Have you tried rendering the cache image in a background thread immediately after the view is drawn from scratch?